# Remove items from linked list after a certain value

Tags: c++

I have this problem, where user inputs n and my program needs to remove any elements form a linked list that come after n and are not equal to n. For example, if my list is 1,2,4,8,4,6,1 and user inputs 4 it should output 1,2,4,4.

So far I only have this code (if list is 1,2,4,8,4,6,1 it outputs 4 8 4 6 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct elem
{
    int num;
    elem *next;
    elem(int n){num = n; next= NULL;}
};

void append(elem *&first, elem *&last, int n){
        elem *p = new elem(n);
        if(first==NULL)
            first=last=p;
        else {
            last->next=p;
            last = p;
        }
}

void deleteListItems(elem *&first, int n){
    elem *p;
    while(first){
        if(first->num==n){

            break;
        }
        else{
            p = first->next;
            delete first;
            first=p;
        }

    }
}

void print(elem *first){
    elem *p = first;
    while(p!=NULL){
        cout<<p->num<<" ";
        p = p->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main () {

    int aa[] = {1,2,4,8,4,6,1};
    elem *first=NULL; 
    elem *last=NULL; 
    elem *p; 
    int n;

    for(int i=0; i<7; ++i){
        append(first, last, aa[i]);
    }

    print(first);

    cout<<"Input n: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    elem *prev;


    print(first);
    deleteListItems(first, n);
    print(first);


    /// delete list
    p = first;
    while (p!=NULL){
        first = first->next;
        delete p;
        p = first;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem needs to be broken down into two parts

1. Find the first instance of the target value.
2. If found, advance to the node past it, and delete every node *not* the target value.

This is made trivial with a pointer to pointer approach. The code to do that is shown below, and I did my best to document how it works in comments.

```
void deleteListItems(elem *&first, int n)
{
    // start at head of the list
    elem **pp = &first;

    // find the first instance of n
    while (*pp && (*pp)->num != n)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;

    // if we found one...
    if (*pp)
    {
        // advance past it
        pp = &(*pp)->next;

        // now walk the rest of the list
        while (*pp)
        {
            // if this does NOT match the target value
            if ((*pp)->num != n)
            {
                // remember the node, overwrite the list pointer
                //  referring to it with it's own 'next', and then
                //  delete now-unhitched node.
                elem *p = *pp;
                *pp = p->next;
                delete p;
            }
            else
            {
                // otherwise, it's another instance of the target
                //  value, so just skip to the next node.
                pp = &(*pp)->next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will work in *every* case I could think of, including lists without duplicates, lists entirely of duplicates, empty lists, single-node lists etc. Worth mentioning, the `tail` pointer in `main` can easily end up dangling, but that was an original problem with your code, and I suspect you'll address that soon enough.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really helpful!